# How do I compute a CID from scratch?

Tags: go, ipfs

For testing purposes, I need to be able to generate a (formally) valid CID in Go, i.e., a fake CID! The function could be given a sequence of bytes, the content type, CID version, etc.
I tried understanding how the CID is built by digging the codebase but couldn't really find my way through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unsure of what you mean by "content type" as I don't believe IPFS cares but it looks like [go-cid](https://github.com/ipfs/go-cid) is what you want:

> ### Creating a CID from scratch
>
> ```golang
> import (
>   cid "github.com/ipfs/go-cid"
>   mc "github.com/multiformats/go-multicodec"
>   mh "github.com/multiformats/go-multihash"
> )
>
> // Create a cid manually by specifying the 'prefix' parameters
> pref := cid.Prefix{
>   Version: 1,
>   Codec: mc.Raw,
>   MhType: mh.SHA2_256,
>   MhLength: -1, // default length
> }
>
> // And then feed it some data
> c, err := pref.Sum([]byte("Hello World!"))
> if err != nil {...}
>
> fmt.Println("Created CID: ", c)
> ```